# highcharts donut pie - different color for the data than its drilldown

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm working on a donut pie chart.

I set the data's color and get the drilldown (which is the object holding the data and configuration for the outer slices) slices' colors to be of the same group of color.
I would like to set a different array of colors to be used in the drilldown objects.
See image attached (the outer slice has two colors: orange and transparent).
See here jsfiddle.net/queequeg/ma6uz/ a playground for donut pie.

[image: needed pie]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set different colors for each of slices: http://jsfiddle.net/KNFJE/36/

For example:

```
    series: [{
        size: '60%',
        innerSize: '30%',
        data: [
            {y: 12, color: 'orange'},
            {y: 10, color: 'gray' },
            {y: 33, color: 'orange'},
            {y: 20, color: 'gray'}
        ]
    },{
        size: '80%',
        innerSize: '60%',
        data: [
            {y: 18, color: 'gray'},
            {y: 11, color: 'orange' },
            {y: 13, color: 'gray'},
            {y: 30, color: 'orange'}
        ]
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the values of color in the code.

```
color: colors[1]
```

set the array index to a different preset color from 0-9.
If you don't want the preset colors from 0-9 you would have to make changes in the highcharts library.

Comment: Hi Tanuj,

In which code?
"color" is an attribute both of dataObj and of dataObj.drilldown .
In any case I've tried it in the jsfiddle mentioned in the question but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: still the outer colors are of the color category like the inner color. try and get orange on the outer slices and white/gray in the inner slices. I couldn't find the way to do it yet.

Comment: the .js you are exporting http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js is defining the preset colors. Try changing the color codes in this file.